# Learning Ruby on Rails. Internet shop / online shopping cart web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been learning Ruby on Rails, HTML, CSS. In my opinion, the best way to learn is doing. Therefore I am going to build an on-line shopping rails application and maybe I'll start a blog that describes how I build the application.

Please recommend me a good tutorial & good resources to help me to achieve my goals. In an ideal world, I'm looking for a step-by-step guide on how to design and develop on-line shopping application: shopping cart, product catalog, product categories, email newsletters, i18n / l10n / m17n (internationalization and the likes), users administration etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Agile Web Development With Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)* is very well-regarded. It's the first book recommended on the Ruby on Rails [documentation site](http://rubyonrails.org/documentation). The book takes you step-by-step through the building of an e-commerce site using Ruby on Rails and the Agile development methodology.

If you don't already know the Ruby programming language you'd do well to learn some of the ideas and syntax behind it. I really like [The Well-Grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black2/). It's extremely thorough and precise, and will give you a firm foundation in Ruby 1.9, which will help immensely as you dive into RoR.

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning Rails for a little while now and I have exhausted the internet looking for decent learning resources.

I would check out the Fourth edition of Agile Web Development with Rails, they build an ecommerce application in that called "Depot"

[Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)